# .gitignore for everything inside the xcuserdata folder does not ignore an xcuserstate file

Tags: xcode, git, gitignore

I'm working in a Xcode project, and I'm trying to configure the .gitignore to not get anything inside the xcuserdata folder.

I have the following .gitignore:

```
# Xcode
.DS_Store
*/build/*
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata
profile
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
.idea/
*.hmap
xcuserdata/*
```

but every time that I build/run the project and execute `git status`, it still shows the following midified file:

```
modified: MyProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/fernando.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

Does anybody have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't ignore UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564257/cant-ignore-userinterfacestate-xcuserstate)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I found the solution

the problem was not in the .gitignore file

the problem was the UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate that was not removed from git server, found the solution in the following link:

[Can't ignore UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564257/cant-ignore-userinterfacestate-xcuserstate)

Comment: Just run this for any file that was previously saved or staged that you want to get ignored `git rm --cached FILE_TO_REMOVE` as cached files will bypass .gitignore configs

Answer (score 13):

Additional info

I have also encountered this and seems not to work since .gitignore still adding them after committing. What I have added does the charm for me

....
this can't be read by the .gitignore:

```
xcuserdata/*
```

adding this works for me:

```
*xcworkspace/xcuserdata/*
```

or to be read:

```
*/xcuserdata/*
```

Comment: `*xcworkspace/xcuserdata/*` worked for me! thank you!

Comment: sure. you should also remove that from cache if you previously commit that file

Comment: None of these work for me. But just xcuserdata, with nothing else does ignore it.

Answer (score 10):

On top of adding `*.xcuserstate` to your `.gitignore` file, remember to remove your cached `*.xcuserstate`

`git rm --cached [YourProjectName].xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/[ YourUsername].xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate`

https://www.programmersought.com/article/1594916500/

Answer (score 6):

Nothing worked but this for me, as I wanted to commit Pods that also have .xcuserdata in it:

```
**/xcuserdata/*
```

Answer (score 3):

If you used git, you can add .gitignore

```
# Xcode
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
.idea/
*.xccheckout
*.moved-aside
xcuserdata/
*.hmap
*.ipa
*.xcworkspace
*.xcuserstate // <--- Here
!default.xcworkspace
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any logic here.
However, in my case only moving
`xcuserdata/`
to the most down of the .gitignore file helped.

Answer (score 1):

For me nothing worked, but this

add this line to your gitignore

```
*.xcuserdata
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, my xcuserdata folder was NOT being tracked by git yet and was still showing up in `git status`. The problem was that I had a space before `xcuserdata` in my .gitignore file.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do

```
 git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory
```

Example:

```
   modified:
        mySwa.com.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/bibscy.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate

   git checkout -- mySwa.com.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/bibscy.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Xcode preferences > Source Control > Git (tab)
2. Under Ignored files add `xcuserdata/`
3. Quit Xcode
4. Clean `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
5. Re-open Xcode project
6. Commit (hopefully you shouldn't see the contents of xcuserdata to be committed)

Note: This would work only if the xcuserdata contents haven't been committed already